# How to modify field in Laravel-Backpack/Settings

Tags: laravel-backpack

[image]

Instead of a text field, I'd like to add a dropdown to Value field in Laravel-Backpack/Settings, `admin/setting/10/edit` page. I appreciate any suggestions.

I used the following in DB settings field but it gives an error.

```
{"name":"value","label":"Value", "title":"Lightbox" ,"type":"select_from_array",
"options":{"lightbox":"lightbox","colorbox1":"colorbox1"}
```

Error

> ErrorException in Fields.php line 28: Undefined index: name in
>   Fields.php line 28 at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined
>   index: name',
>   '/Users/sokada/Code/backpack-ceci/vendor/backpack/crud/src/PanelTraits/Fields.php',
>   '28', array('field' => array(), 'form' => 'both',
>   'complete_field_array' => array())) in Fields.php line 28 at
>   CrudPanel->addField(array()) in SettingCrudController.php line 69

Line #28 in Fields.php is followings.

```
...
    // if the label is missing, we should set it
    if (! isset($complete_field_array['label'])) {
        $complete_field_array['label'] = ucfirst($complete_field_array['name']);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me.

[image]

Are you sure you didn't miss a paranthesis at the end?

```
{"name":"value","label":"Value", "title":"Lightbox" ,"type":"select_from_array", "options":{"lightbox":"lightbox","colorbox1":"colorbox1"}}
```